# Delphi VCL Style for one Form

Tags: delphi, themes, vcl, delphi-11-alexandria, vcl-styles

I´m trying to create a preview form for the selected style like this:

```
procedure TConfigForm.btnStylePreviewClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var frmStylePreview := TFrmStylePreview.Create(self);
  try
    frmStylePreview.StyleName := cbStyle.Text;
    frmStylePreview.ShowModal();
  finally
    frmStylePreview.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This works fine, but only if my current VCL style is not set to "Windows" (native Windows components). But the Styles are still enabled. Is there a workaround for this problem? And why is this behaviour like this? Thanks!

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Comment: Delphi 11 Alexandria

Comment: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-29754

Comment: Thanks Uwe, so there is no solution for this and there is no possibility to show a style preview when Style is set to "Windows". This is really sad...